# How to run AppleScript from Keynote?

Tags: applescript, keynote

Within Keynote and using AppleScript, I’m trying to emulate a macro used in a Windows PowerPoint file by a colleague. The macro is executed by clicking on a customized button. So, I wonder if the same feature can be replicated in Keynote. Is it possible to run some AppleScript code within Keynote, and how?

Comment: So, your colleague has a macOS PowerPoint file which has a form control button that runs some AppleScript code when clicked on and you wonder if something similar can be done from within macOS Keynote. Is that right?

Comment: My colleague has a PPT macro on Windows that activates on a click. I want to do something similar but using Keynote and AppleScript.

Comment: By PPT macro, do you mean a macro run from within a Windows PowerPoint file?

Comment: Yes; saved using the extension “.pptm”

Answer (score 0):

In Keynote or other iWork software such as Numbers or Pages, it is not possible to create a "clickable customized button", which is officially called a form control button in Microsoft Office applications. However, it is possible to run automation code from Keynote or other iWork software via the (Keynote->)Services menu or a keyboard shortcut.

Such automation code, which is usually called a macro in Microsoft Office, can be created, among other things, as a Quick Action in macOS. A Quick Action is created from within the Automator app and you may or may not need to include some AppleScript code in it to achieve your objective.

If you really want to do this, my suggestion would be for you to review [the Automator user guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome/mac) and see if you can achieve your objective using the ready actions in the Automator library. If the ready actions turn out be insufficient, you can add some AppleScript or JavaScript code to your Quick Action as also described in the Automator user guide to achieve your objective. There are many excellent sources in the Internet on either Automator or AppleScript but here is [the official AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1) for a start if you need it.

After researching, learning and trying these tools for at least a while, if you get stuck, come back to this site and ask a new question which should include a sufficiently detailed description of your objective and what you have done so far in terms of implementation.